# Unknown part from an old television

Tags: components

I found this in an old television. I'm very curious as to what it is. Please enlighten me! I'm thinking, some kind of over-voltage protection?

[image]

Comment: How about a side view?

Comment: That's probably the worst possible view, not to mention a small object in the middle of a large picture. Also, is it really that green color or were you just too lazy to correct it? If you show us several views, in focus, and reasonably cropped, we might be able to identify the part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like the thermistor assembly from the degaussing section of a CRT colour TV. Was it connected to a large coil of wire that srrounded the back of the CRT?

But as Olin says, very poor photo.

Comment: Alright! I'm sorry I was in a rush and on my phone.. yes it was so that's probably it :-) thanks